# validate contact form with jquery and php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to validate a contact form with jquery and php but I always get false from php even though it's working fine. I'm going to explain with my code:
This is my html:

```
<form method='post'>

    <label>Name<input id="name" type="text" name="name" /></label>

    <label>Email Address<input id="email" type="text" name="email" /></label>

    <label>Subject<input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" /></label>

    <label>Message<textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea></label>

    <label><input type="button" value="Submit Form" id="button_form" /></label>

</form>
```

This is my js code:

```
function validaForm(){
    // Campos de texto
    if($('#email').val() == ""){
        alert("You must fill in at least the email field.");
        $('#email').focus();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

$('#button_form').click( function() {     
        if(validaForm()){                              
            $.post("php/form.php",$('form').serialize(),function(res){
                if(res == 1){
                    alert("Your e-mail has been sent, Thank you for contacting us. We will answer you as soon as possible.");

                } else if(res == 0){
                    alert("Sorry, your e-mail couldn't been sent, please try again later."); 
                } else {
                    alert("Others.");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

This is my .php file:

```
<?php
require 'class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();                                     
$mail->Host = 'smtp.domain.com';  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                              
$mail->Username = 'myacc@mydomain.com';                            
$mail->Password = 'pass';                          
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            

$mail->From = 'myacc@mydomain.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Contact Form';
$mail->AddAddress('myacc@mydomain.com');               

$mail->AddAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         
$mail->AddAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  

$mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];

$mensajeFinal = "Message";

$mail->Body    = $mensajeFinal;

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;    
};

?>
```

Ok, Everything is working fine, I mean, it sends the e-mail but the problem is that I always get false from php file no matter if it sends or not the e-mail.
Am I doing something wrong?? Is there something I am missing??
I would appreciate any help. Thanxs a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `echo` here, this is not function. `return` is used for returning result from functions. Also remove the `;` after

```
else {...};
          ^

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo false;
} else {
    echo true;    
}
```

Comment: You were faster than me. :D

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge FGITW. :D

Comment: I've been like hours looking for this... omg.... Thanxs a lot.. I'll accept your answer in 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

In your click function

```
$('#button_form').click( function() { .... } );
```

Be sure to `return false` if validaForm returns false

Answer (score 0):

Hi put your code between

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

Looks like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#button_form').click( function() {     
      if(validaForm()){                              
          $.post("php/form.php",$('form').serialize(),function(res){
              if(res == 1){
                  alert("Your e-mail has been sent, Thank you for contacting us. We will answer you as soon as possible.");

              } else if(res == 0){
                  alert("Sorry, your e-mail couldn't been sent, please try again later."); 
              } else {
                  alert("Others.");
              }
          });
      }
  });
});
```